# I want to compress an image size to send it api params as an form data by dio in flutter by FlutterNativeImage package

Tags: flutter, dart

But I'm facing this problem again and again "Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method compressWithFileAndGetFile on channel flutter_image_compress)"

Trying to compress the image by this:

```
File? compressedFile = await FlutterNativeImage.compressImage(
          scannedImage!.path,
          quality: 20,
          percentage: 60);
```

and receiving an error `Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method compressWithFileAndGetFile on channel flutter_image_compress)`

Answer (score 0):

The error **Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException** occurs mostly when we add new package in project but we don't stop the app and directly run it when it is already running, So if you stop the project then run again the issue gets resolved. Also try running pub get command.

Answer (score 0):

```
flutter clean
flutter run
```

it will be enough